# https(apache + ssl) is only available from locahost, how to configure to visit it by domain name?

Tags: apache, ssl, windows-server-2003, xampp, localhost

apache + ssl is configured using xampp on windows server 2003. http content has no problem by domain name, but https content can only be visited from localhost. "netstat -a" shows

Proto  Local Address     Remote Address  State
...
TCP    hostname:https    hostname:0      Listening
...

How to config to enable https via domain name?

---

Found the reason. Another program take the 443 port so apache https failed. use "netstat -a -o -n" can get the detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can already access apache using this domain name.
Take a look in your ports.conf, usually found at 
/etc/apache2/ports.conf

It should contain a line like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

and also

```
Listen 8443 https
```

Comment: sorry that I'm working on a windows server, it seems there is no such a file named ports.conf :(  btw, http content is no problem via domain name.